# JavaScript: For-Loop does not run?

Tags: javascript, for-loop

Why the for loop does not run?

- The Error-Console is empty
- The function `countfiles` return a whole number
- `parseInt(countfiles())` also not work too

Here my Code:

```
function set_default_value() {
    var element = document.getElementsByName('fields');
    for (var i = countfields(); i < element.length; ++i) {
        element[i].value = "default";
    }
}
```

Why does not run?

**EDIT:**

- Countfields is lower than element.length
- The function is running
- Countfield return a number like 0, 1, 2, 3, ...

Here's the function `countfields`

```
function countfields() {
    var field_counter = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
        if (typeof document.getElementsByName('other_fields')[i] != "undefined") {
        var field_counter = field_counter + 1; 
        }
    }
    return field_counter; 
}
```

Comment: I would provide the source to `countfields()` and also the related markup

Comment: The number returned by `countfields` could be greater than `element.length`

Comment: what does countfields() return and also paste some snippet of your html structure

Comment: yes, perhaps countfields() is greater than element.length

Comment: Is countfields() >= element.length?

Comment: please console log counfields() and element.length and tell us what you get

Comment: PLEASE SHOW `COUNTFIELDS()`

Comment: Your always right... countfields return a greater number than elemt.length ..... thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@varunachar touched on the issue in one of his comments:

> [The number returned by countfields could be greater than element.length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14817863/javascript-for-loop-does-not-run#comment20757041_14817863)

In this line:

```
for (var i = countfields(); i < element.length; ++i)
```

Read this `i < element.length` as *"as long as `i` is less than `element.length`, do stuff"*. Or, if `countfields()` is equal or greater, nothing happens.

1 `other_fields`: http://jsfiddle.net/D5ZHV/ works
6 `other_fields`: http://jsfiddle.net/Ay6BN/ does **not** work

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
        var field_counter = field_counter + 1;
```

To

```
        field_counter = field_counter + 1;
```

In `countfields()` function. You are declaring `field_counter` inside the for loop which is wrong

Comment: That indeed looks incorrect, but in JavaScript it will still work the same way.

Answer (score 0):

```
function countfields() {
    var field_counter = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
        if(typeof document.getElementsByName('other_fields')[i] != "undefined") {
        var field_counter = field_counter + 1; } }
    return field_counter; }
```

var always define the scope of the variable.
Inside the if doing `var field_counter` will create a variable with scope inside the if-statement.

you should write as

```
field_counter = field_counter + 1;
```

If you test your countfields() it should always return 0;

Also try doing `console.log(elements)`